# Why is this while loop not behaving as I expect?

Tags: c++, while-loop

The problem is that the while loop isn't exiting even if the user has entered the correct name format only if the first input was entered incorrectly. This problem doesn't occur when the user enters the name correctly the first time.

```
void inputclass::validateName(string name) {
    bool flag = true
    while (flag == true) {

        for (int i=0;  i < name.length(); i++) {

            if (name[i] != ' ') {

                if (!isalpha(name[i])) {

                    cout << "You have entered incorrectly. Please try again. "  << endl;

                    setName();

                } else if (i == name.length()-1) {

                    cout << "Welcome " << name << endl;
                    flag = false;   //break out of while loop

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void inputclass::setName() {

    string name;
    cout << "Please enter your name: " << endl;
    getline(cin, name);
    validateName(name);
}
```

Comment: No one knows here _'what you have posted previously'_, and at least I'm not willing to check your profile for this now. Please post self contained questions!

Comment: `validateName` calling `setName` calling `validateName`? this is what stack overflows (hehe) are made from.

Comment: Sorry πάντα ῥεῖ, but that's a bit rude IMO. You could've said that more politely.

Comment: @jellybean_232 Sorry, if I sounded rude, it wasn't meant so. I just wanted to point out the fact, you should keep your question really self contained. As it is, it certainly lacks sufficient information what your problems really are. Sorry :-/ ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that's quite alright. I can understand a lot of people do that on here and you must be sick of seeing it. It's fine, I normally don't do this but a fellow user suggested that I repost, which i found a bit odd, but i did so anyway.

Comment: @jellybean_232 BTW, the worst thing you can get here for a question is `0` votes. Everything else will generate attraction to other users ;) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not too bothered about votes. I'm more concerned about my program and whether it works or not.

Comment: @jellybean_232 Sure, you don't really need to be bothered about votes or not. The point is: No matter, if votes are going up or down, you have a better chance to get an appropriate answer, and users are attracted to take a look at your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is c++,there is no array bounds checking. You are reading past the end of the array and isalpha() is returning true. Swap the if and else around and check if i us at the end of the array first.

Comment: woops that's what i mean. I meant to put a hyphen after "exiting". I didn't actually mean exiting c++. that's just weird =P

Answer (score 1):

you seem to have difficulties finding a logic for solving your problem. just start with some pseudo-code and start implementing once you know what you need. I guess you are looking for something like

```
bool valid = false
while not valid:
    name = setName()
    valid = validate(name)
```

then there's no need in recursion. just implement a `setName()` that reads user input and returns a string. and a `validate()` that performs the validation and returns a bool. simple, huh?

Answer (score 1):

1. Please don't call validation functions recursively, that is a terrible practice which could lead to stack overflows
2. As you wrote it, **you need to escape the recursive functions by entering valid inputs per each single wrong digit you entered in one of the parents**

Hint: a more decent way to do it is to have the validation function use its return value and return `false` if the input isn't valid. Then the parent might try again if it suits it.